# Need some help with a bird injury. Urgent!

Tags: birds, injury, first-aid

So my dog found this little bird, which fell from mid flight or maybe it was sitting on a branch,  I don't know,  and brought it to me. My dog didn't bite it or hurt it in any other way.
It's a really small bird barely even fills the palm of my hand. I saw it couldn't fly properly or even sit upright so I took it in. After checking I realized that the nail/ claw on one of its feet on the third digit is missing. There are no other visible injuries and it's wings are working just fine. So my guess is, because of the missing nail it can't hold on to anything and perhaps it's also making it lose its balance during flight.

I really have no idea whatsoever of what I should do in order to help it. 
For now I'm just keeping it in a makeshift cage, gave it a soft place to rest and some food and water; I couldn't just leave it because there are many cats in the neighborhood.

I would really appreciate some help and advice with what I should do with it.

Also if birds lose their nails/ claws like this do they grow it back?

I've really been worried about this, so any form of your input is welcomed.

*UPDATE: it can't even fly properly, just like a few meters at Max

P. S. : you can follow this link to look at what kind of bird it is: http://www.ngkenya.com/fauna/lonchura_cucullata.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough money to spend, try caring for it and get some medicine, but be careful. Ask advice from other bird owners or vets and see if they can help or prescribe something. Try your own dong vet, they should be nicer. Make sure the bird is safe, warm comfy and has food and water. The only thing now is to see whats wrong with it. Take it to a shelter maybe.

Comment: Update: the bird is fine and we set it free a day ago. Still don't actually know what was wrong with it but it seems whatever it was it's healed now. Thanks for all your inputs!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say bring it to a vet that would do it pro-bono asap. It's not a pet and should probably get back into nature as soon as possible.

Comment: So I did contact two different vets but they didn't show much interest helping the bird let alone doing it pro-bono. There was one who said he'd help but it's on the other side of town and I don't even have a proper cage to take the bird in. So that's why I had to ask for help here. And yes I also wanna get it back asap.